# What is the purpose of files[] in .info?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've just started learning discovering the changes to Drupal 7, and I just found the `files[]` array now required in the `mymodule.info`. From what I've found, it is required to add the `mymodule.module` file to the list, but what other uses does it have?

From what I've read I figured I should be able to separate my code into several files, for example I wanted to make a `mymodule.blocks.inc` to contain all the code for my blocks, but it seems like the `mymodule_block_info()` function never runs.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not how it is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/542202) says:

> files (Optional) Drupal now supports a dynamic-loading code registry.
>   To support it, all modules must now declare any code files containing class or interface declarations in the .info file.

This is only used if the file you specify in `files[]` contains a class or an interface. If so, the file will be auto-loaded only when needed.
No other files should be declared using `files[]`.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning it was to make a files registry for each module, but it's not longer used as Drupal do it by himself.

If you want separate your module in multiple files, you should include them in the top of your .module file.

Comment: It is not necessary to include them on top of the module file, as Drupal has a hook that reports on which files some hooks are contained; see [hook_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7).

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, files specified as `files[]` are meant to be supporting files and called upon when needed.  Implemented default Drupal hooks should be specified in the `.module` file or in the  `$module.$group.inc` file in order for Drupal to recognize them.  See [hook_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7).

Also, see the note in the documentation under *files* at http://drupal.org/node/542202.